# Facebook Socialite Error 404: Page not found

Tags: laravel-socialite

I am setting up `Facebooking socialite` on my existing website and encountered an **404 error when I click "Login With Facebook " button**. The error is:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.

I don't know whether the error is from the routing or it is from something else.

The designate url for the button is: https://ktest1.domainforplaying.com/auth/redirect/facebook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to setup routes for socialite to use to connect to Facebook. Please see the official documentation:

https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/socialite#routing

Comment: Thank for the suggestion.